# GENKI Vocab Cards app doesn't play sound

Tags: applications, audio, iphone

I have just purchased the GENKI Vocab Cards app for reviewing vocabulary from the GENKI Japanese textbook. It is a flashcards application. Every card is equipped with a loudspeaker button that is supposed to sound the pronunciation of the card's word or phrase when clicked. However, clicking the button produces no sound.

[image: A card within the GENKI Vocal Cards app]

I have no problem hearing the playback of a Voice Memos recording.

[image]

What steps can I take to try and fix this issue?

---

iOS App: GENKI Vocab Cards, Version 2.2.0

Device: iPhone 7

iOS: 10.3.1 (14E304)

Issue: Pressing the "play/speak" button results in no sound output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Untoggle the mute switch** at the top left of your iPhone. It will vibrate if it's muted. Unmuting won't make the device vibrate.

Make sure to increase the volume with the volume buttons.

---

Regarding Voice Memo.app

Tap the **speaker icon** at the top right to toggle the output (earpiece/loudspeaker).

Then **adjust the volume** with the volume buttons on the left of your iPhone.